# Wordpress image files

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, media

I have a list of products that I have imported into WooCommerce using a csv file.  This includes product description along with image names ie, image1.jpg, image2.jpg however when I upload these images using the Wordpress media function it renames it to image11.jpg image21.jpg etc.

I have too many image files to rename them so can someone help me out, I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the images are stored in the database but not on the FTP. So don't upload them via the media manager, instead upload them directly via FTP into the upload dir. Pay attention for the correct paths of the images.

Comment: BTW: Wordpress renames your images, because the title of your images you upload still exist in the database but not physical on the FTP.

Comment: When it worked, could you please mark my answer as "correct" ?